# Ajax form requires two clicks on submit before fades out

Tags: html, ajax, forms

So there is obviously something wrong in my syntax. Validation is ok. When I click submit the form sends email to me and then it deletes the value of my inputs. Everything is ok until now. But it does not fade out as it should. If I click on submit again, then it fades out. Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#form1').ajaxForm({
        beforeSubmit: validate
    });

    function validate(formData, jqForm, options) {
        var name = $('input[name=name]').fieldValue();
        var email = $('input[name=email]').fieldValue();
        var message = $('textarea[name=message]').fieldValue();

        if (!name[0]) {
            alert('Please enter a value for name');
            return false;
        }
        if (!email[0]) {
            alert('Please enter a value for email');
            return false;
        }
        if (!message[0]) {
            alert('Please enter a value for message');
            return false;
        }

        else {
            $("#form1").ajaxForm(function () {
        $("#formplic").fadeOut(1000, function () {
            $(this).html("<img src='images/postauto3.png'/>").fadeIn(2000);
        });
    });
        var message = $('textarea[name=message]').val('');
        var name = $('input[name=name]').val('');
        var email = $('input[name=email]').val('');

            } 
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I figured it out. The issue was that after else I stated again ajax.Form. I deleted that line and it works pefectly. So, if someone makes the same mistake as me, delete $("#form1").ajaxForm(function ().